# Getting titles from an array of IDs

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have two custom post types called actors and movies. In movies, I have a custom meta box that got data from actors post type.

When an actor is selected in movie post, the values (post_id, meta_key and meta_values) are stored in postmeta table.

So I build a page to show all movie info. Fot that, I'm using WP_Query:

```
     <?php
        $args_movie = array('post_type' => 'movie','posts_per_page' => -1);
        $movie_posts = new WP_Query($args_movie);

        if($movie_posts->have_posts()) : 
           while($movie_posts->have_posts()) : 
           $movie_posts->the_post();
     ?>

        <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>

     <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        Oops, there are no posts.
     <?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine for me. Now I'm trying to show all actors associated with each movie. This script return an array of IDs:

```
$actors= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'actors'); print_r($actors);
```

But how can I using this array to get actor's titles?

**SOLVED**

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'actors','orderby' => 'ASC','post__in' => $areas);
```

[more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ids` in `$actor` the following way to get the actor's title.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'actors',
    'post__in'  => $actors,
);

$actors_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $actors_posts->have_posts() ) :
    while( $actors_posts->have_posts() ) : 
        $actors_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        echo 'Oops, there are no posts.';
<?php endif; ?>
```